# Azure Storage Table API REST with Curl

Tags: bash, rest, azure, curl, azure-table-storage

I need help to print an entity with Rest in shell script. I tried several ways, but without success.

Here is my code, running it, it will return all entities in my table.

But I need it to return only a specific value and that is only using PartitionKey.

```
#!/bin/bash

# List the tables in an Azure storage container.

storage_account="Secret"
table_name="teste"
access_key="Secret"

table_store_url="table.core.windows.net"
authorization="SharedKey"

request_method="GET"
request_date=$(TZ=GMT LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 date "+%a, %d %h %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
#request_date="Mon, 18 Apr 2016 05:16:09 GMT"
storage_service_version="2018-03-28"

# HTTP Request headers
x_ms_date_h="x-ms-date:$request_date"
x_ms_version_h="x-ms-version:$storage_service_version"

# Build the signature string
canonicalized_resource="/${storage_account}/${table_name}"


string_to_sign="${request_method}\n\n\n$request_date\n${canonicalized_resource}"

# Decode the Base64 encoded access key, convert to Hex.
decoded_hex_key="$(echo -n $access_key | base64 -d -w0 | xxd -p -c256)"


# Create the HMAC signature for the Authorization header
signature=$(printf "$string_to_sign" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:$decoded_hex_key" -binary |  base64 -w0)

authorization_header="Authorization: $authorization $storage_account:$signature"

curl -s \
  -H "$authorization_header" \
  -H "$x_ms_date_h" \
  -H "$x_ms_version_h" \
  -H "Content-Length: 0" \
  -H "accept: application/json;odata=nometadata" \
 "https://${storage_account}.${table_store_url}/${table_name}"
```

In this case, I need to change the end of the string "string_to_sign" and the last line of the Curl.

If I insert at the end (PartitionKey='name',RowKey = 'Gabriel')"

Getting the two lines like this:

```
string_to_sign = "$ {request_method} \ n \ n \ n $ request_date \ n $ {canonicalized_resource} (PartitionKey = 'name', RowKey = Gabriel)"

"https://${storage_account}.${table_store_url}/${table_name}(PartitionKey='nome',RowKey='Gabriel')"
```

It will return only the entity with PartitionKey "name" and Rowkey "Gabriel".

But as I said before, I must use only Partition Key. If I change the end of the two lines to (PartitionKey = 'name') only, it returns the following error:

```
The number of keys specified in the URI does not match number of key properties for the resource
```

I tried using the $ filter option, changing the end of the two lines to `()$filter=(PartitionKey%20ge%20'Name')`, however it happens error when passing through the Printf.

By putting `()$filter=(PartitionKey%%20ge%%20'Name')`, Two %, it passes, but occurs authentication error on request.

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature
```

Can someone help me?

I need to use PartitionKey because in these tests I am using a table that I created and I have the value of RowKey for tests, but where I need to implement, I do not have access to RowKey, I would pass the value of PartitionKey which is a telephone number to obtain the result of the RowKey, which is an Id.

Used the following documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to change `string_to_sign` when querying entity, see [Authorization Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#Subheading2).

> The query string should include the question mark and the comp parameter (for example, ?comp=metadata). No other parameters should be included on the query string.

If you want to get whole entity using PartitionKey, change url to($ need encoding to %24)

```
https://${storage_account}.${table_store_url}/${table_name}?%24filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'YourPartitionKey'
```

Or if you only want to retrieve RowKey, append `&%24select=RowKey` after that.

Also `-H "Content-Length: 0"` is useless, just delete it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jerry! 

Seeing this code, I saw that the problem was in the "$filter" part, then change to "%24filter" works fine.